# How to add tool-tips working in div elements to li elements in my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using PHP, MySQL, jQuery, Smarty, etc. for my website.

I want to implement the tool-tip functionality on one of my webpages. For it I have developed some sample jQuery code as a Proof of Concept.

See [**Proof of Concept Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/66nLy/9/).

However, when I tried to implement the same functionality in my website I'm facing some issues. On my webpage I'm using `<table>` and I want to use the jQuery functionality within it.

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

In the Fiddle I'm showing the tool-tip menu on `click` of an image but in my website I want to show the tool-tip on a text like "**Report question issue - QUE37261**" and other such similar titles.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<table class="base-table selection-table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <tr class="evenRow" id="37261">
        <td class="question">
            <ul class="tabl-head">
                <li>Question 1.</li>
                <li class="center-align">**Report question issue - QUE37261**</li>
                <li class="right-align"><a class="change_ps_question" href="change_practice_sheet_question.php?question_id=37261&practice_sheet_id=3"><label class="bright" style="cursor:pointer;" >Change Question</label></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="options w-auto">
                <li><strong>Question:</strong>
Pair of contrasting characters controlling the same trait is called:</li>
                <li><strong>Answer:</strong>

                    <p><b style="font-size:13px;">1.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; Factors
                        <br />
                    </p>
                    <p><b style="font-size:13px;">2.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; alleles
                        <br />
                    </p>
                    <p><b style="font-size:13px;">3.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; alloloci
                        <br />
                    </p>
                    <p><b style="font-size:13px;">4.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; paramorphs
                        <br />
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li><strong>Correct Answer Option : 2</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The actual table is too large and contains many records. For brevity I have shown only one record.

Comment: Use <span> tag of HTML5 for showing tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest solution is to use [jQuery UI - Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default).

With this, you can simply attach an attribute `title` to the elements that you want to display the tooltip.

For example, taking some code from your example:

```
  <li>Question 1.</li>
  <li class="center-align" title="my tooltip message text">**Report question issue - QUE37261**</li>
```

And then, somewhere in the head tag:

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $( document ).tooltip();
    });
  </script>
```

In this case is the `<li>` element that raise the tooltip, if you want only the text in it, you can do in this manner:

```
 <li>Question 1.</li>
 <li class="center-align">**Report <span title="my tooltip message text">question</span> issue - QUE37261**</li>
```

In this case, only the word-text "question" raise the tooltip.

You can even do [complex tooltip content](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content).

Alternatively if you use the `title` attribute somewhere for other purpose, you can target the tooltip only for some classes that you define (the `title` attribute should ever be defined in these elements). For example:

```
$(".my_tooltip_class_element").tooltip();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add title attribute to show tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using JQuery you can add a hover event as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.question li').hover(function() {
     clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    //toolify()
}, function() {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        //removetooltip.
    }, 500);
    $(this).data('timeout', t);
});
});
```